# Is it possible to integrate Jasmine into cruise control.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, jasmine

Is it possible to automatically run a jasmine test suite as part of a cruise control.net build?

And If so how?

Comment: I had the same problem, but ended up using NQUnit, because no changes are needed on Cruise Control. See http://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2011/03/13/nqunit-javascript-testing-within-net-ci/

Comment: This question might be too specific for many to answer. For what it's worth, Jasmine comes with a JUnit XML logger which many CI tools can read, maybe also yours.

Answer (score 1):

My server code is C# and I already had my CI server running lots of unit tests.  So I added a unit test that uses Watin to launch a browser to run the Jasmine tests and check the results.  It took a morning to get all the pieces playing happily together.

An alternative might be to investigate NJasmine -- I saw this was available on NuGet but didn't pursue this myself partly due to lack of documentation.

Also, if you're using ReSharper, you might like to look at their integration with QUnit: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/03/resharper-6-introduces-support-for-javascript-unit-testing/ (there's every chance they'll integrate it with Jasmine too).  Although this is aimed at running JS UTs within Visual Studio, you might find it offers you a "hook" to run them from your CI server too.